# Añadir etiqueta extra (para una tercera variable) en un eje en ggplot

Tags: r

Tengo un código que imprime una serie de datos en un gráfico. La variable dependiente y es representada en el eje derecho, la variable independiente x es representada en el eje x, y la variable independiente z es representada en el eje izquierdo. El código es el siguiente:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data %>% 
    mutate(y=case_when(
    y >= 2 ~ "high",
    y  < 2 & y >= 1 ~ "medium",
    y  < 1 ~ "low")) %>%
  mutate_all(as.factor) %>%
  mutate(y = factor(y, levels = c("low", "medium", "high"))) %>% 
  mutate(z = factor(z, levels = c(1, 0.5, 0))) %>% 
  group_by(y, z, x) %>%
  count() %>%
  group_by(z, x) %>% 
  mutate(prop = n / sum(n)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = prop, fill = y, order = y)) + 
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(z~.,switch='y') + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "RdYlBu") + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  scale_y_continuous(position = "right") +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(prop)), 
            position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5, reverse = TRUE),
            size = 3) +
  labs(title="Plot", x = "x", y = "y", fill = "y") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=12))
```

The result is this:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría añadir una etiqueta en el eje izquierdo. He probado varias cosas pero no parece tan fácil con ggplot.

Comment: El problema es que no existe eje izquierdo. Lo que tienes son tres gráficos correspondiente a tres valores de la variable `z`, y un eje `y` compartido por los tres, que muestras en la derecha. Podrías intentar algo como esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22825447/6836377

Comment: Y por supuesto, al menos para indicar el nombre de la variable con una solución más simple, podrías hacer algo así `facet_grid(paste("z =",z)~.,switch='y')`